# How to display data from this API function?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am completely inexperienced with HTML and js development, but I'm currently working on a project where I take an API from a site, which contains GPS data, and display it on my webpage. I'm using a function from jQuery to achieve this.

(Context: Inside an html file, this code is in `<script>`)

```
$.getJSON("link_of_API", function(data){

console.log(data);

});
```

The API url itself works fine, found here at https://www.followmee.com/apidoc.aspx

The JSON looks like this:

```
Data: {"Data":[{"DeviceName":"","DeviceID":"xxx","Latitude":xxx,"Longitude": xxx]}
```

I want to display this data in just text, what should I do from here?

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? Accessing the fields of the JSON, or displaying data on a web page?

Comment: @Bamar Both. I'm not even sure the current code works.

Comment: Obviously it doesn't, or you wouldn't be here. But you need to post what you tried, so we can identify what you did wrong and show how to fix it.